# How to dump an unknown memory structure within C

Tags: c, memory

Assume the following program has a variety of structures used for storage (there are only 2 here) and
one structure is used for processing the storage structures.

The structure1 and structure2 structures are the storage structures and vary in size. These structures are stored sequentially within memory and the structure mainStructure traverses the memory to process each structure.

The structure1 and structure2 structures vary in size and these can be stored in the chunk of memory in any order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
    {
    char attr1[30];
    int attr2;
    float attr3;
    } structure1;

typedef struct
    {
    short attr4;
    short attr5[5];
    char  attr6[40];
    } structure2;

typedef struct
    {
    char *headPointer;
    int mainStructureAttr1;
    char nameOfStruct[28];
    char *structPointer;
    } mainStructure;

int main(void)
{
    structure1 s1a = { "Hello From Structure 1 a.", 1, 3.14159f};
    structure1 s1b = { "Hello From Structure 1 b.", 2, 9.87654f};
    structure2 s2a = {"Hello From Structure 2", 3, 5.6789f};
    mainStructure mainS = {"\0", 101, "Hello From Main Structure.", "\0"};

    //Allocate a chunk of memory to store all the data. 
    mainS.structPointer = (char*)calloc(3, 100);//total 300
    ///1st structure inserted into memory
    memcpy(mainS.structPointer, &s1a, sizeof(structure1));
    //set headPointer to the start of the memory
    mainS.headPointer = mainS.structPointer;
    //Move the tracking pointer to the next part of memory.
    mainS.structPointer += sizeof(structure1);
    ///2nd structure inserted into memory
    memcpy(mainS.structPointer, &s2a, sizeof(structure2));
    //Move the tracking pointer to the next part of memory.
    mainS.structPointer += sizeof(structure2);
    ///3rd structure inserted into memory
    memcpy(mainS.structPointer, &s1b, sizeof(structure1));
    dumpMemory(mainS);
    printf("Done \n");

    return 0;
}

void dumpMemory(mainStructure mainS)
{
    printf ("=====Start Memory Dump=====\n");
    printf ("%s", mainS.headPointer);
    printf ("\n=====End Memory Dump=====\n");
}
```

The structure mainStructure uses one pointer to traverse the memory and another point which points to the beginning of the memory structure.

How can I used the pointer which references this large piece of memory and dump it all out. 
The above code attempts to do it but since %s is used it stops at the first 0.

Imagine that dumpMemory() is part of some external library and its only purpose is to dump a section of memory.

How can dumpMemory() be coded so it dumps out all the memory that headPointer points too which is the beginning of the memory with all the structured data?

Comment: Unless you know the size then it's not possible. The structure itself doesn't know where it ends or starts in memory. It doesn't have to.

Comment: how can `structure1` and `structure2` actually vary in size?

Comment: If you do not dynamically create memory, then it is created on the stack, and you do not need to _dump_ (or `free`) it.

Comment: ..and `mainS.headPointer = mainS.structPointer;` should really be: `mainS.headPointer = &mainS.structPointer;`.  Still, this creates no memory, it just assigns the location of one item to a pointer type.

Comment: `char *headPointer;` is a good starting point. Learn more about [linked lists](https://www.google.com/search?q=linked+lists&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIL817IL817&oq=linked+lists&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Next, when you will walk over that list you will need some additional members in your structs that will help you to differentiate between them. Of if your structs follow each other in the memory (which is NOT guaranteed with your code) then you might not need linked list - just struct differentiator

Comment: Dump it in hexadecimal?

Comment: Please provide a [example]. I see more than one error even without trying to compile your source.